No perfomance settings Ubuntu 24.10
installed Ubuntu 24.10 a few days ago, everything was fine, but just noticed - missing performance settings on my laptop (power saving, balance, performance). What could this be related to and how to fix it?


Screenshot not on english, but you can see - no checkbox for select perfomance
